# Evolve class by adding new methods

Tags: c++

Let's say I have some class

```
class A {
...
};
```

with some variables and methods encapsulated inside. My question is, if it is possible that class can "learn" new methods - some function is putting new methods inside the class body.

For example, I have an empty class

```
class Draw {};
```

and some function in my program reads data from file and based on that can draw Circle, Square etc. Is it possible to put these drawing methods inside Draw class body so that it grows dynamically ?

Comment: And this function compiles the new functions and injects them into the old binary?

Comment: You should consider other language to do such things. C++ compiler implies strong static checks on the code and you are definetely forbidden to do any move changing the type through program. However, you can do such things in two steps using code generation, that is, write a program in C++ that parses your file and creates a new C++ code file based on received info. Then you compile the new code file and achive the result. But any time you have a new data file, you should generate new code and new exe.

Comment: try in some other language, you cant do it in c++

Comment: Though something like that could be 'emulated' by integrating an interpreter, e.g. lua.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

```
class Draw
{
public:
    ReturnType call(const std::string& methodName, ArgTypes args)
    {
       return methods[methodName](this, args);
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<
       std::string,
       std::function<ReturnType(Draw*, ArgTypes)>
    > methods;
};
```

Add to `methods` as you see fit.

(I have abstracted away `ReturnType` and `ArgTypes`; pick what you need there.)

Comment: Of course you can add function pointers in a container. But I am not sure this was meant. The functions must already exist somewhere in the code. Do you have a use case for your solution? Currently I don't see the point doing it this way.

Comment: Nice one. I'm a beginner but I was asking myself if this design is really totally safe ?

Comment: Oh yes, the design is safe. Putting functions in a container make sense in many situations. I just don't see it for the above example. Of course this does not mean, there is not use case where this is a viable solution. I am curious to see one. :-)

Comment: Ok, Found one possible use case: It could replace a switch/case.

Comment: @Greenflow _"Do you have a use case for your solution"_ Yes: the scenario posited in the question.

Comment: I, and several others, understood with 'learning new methods' methods, which don't exist anywhere in the program and are loaded at runtime. This of course is not possible. Just adding functions from somewhere else in the program into a class and call them via a string...What's the point?

Comment: @Greenflow: The point is to achieve the goal. `methods` in my code is a map. You can add to it. You add functions to it. Once you've added a new function, you have a new function. I don't know how to make it clearer for you.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to "My question is, if it is possible that class can "learn" new methods - some function is putting new methods inside the class body" is no